# How to import types from a third party library?

Tags: typescript

I have a third party library which has types declared in `node_modules/thisLibrary/dist/interfaces.d.ts`. TS compiler resolves the types used in a function imported from this library, because tooltip displays them and also errors appear when I make incorrect assignments, but when I want to declare a variable using the library's type (which I obviously need to do), I get the error `Cannot find name 'TypeName'`:

```
let myVar: TypeName; // `Cannot find name 'TypeName'`
```

I have the following settings in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
   "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue",
        "tests/**/*.ts",
        "tests/**/*.tsx",
        "node_modules/thisLibrary/dist/interfaces.d.ts",
        "../node_modules/thisLibrary/dist/interfaces.d.ts", // attempting various paths
    ],
 "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types",
        "node_modules/thisLibrary/dist",
    ],
```

I added the `include` and `typeRoots` following some answers, but nothing helps. Compiler does not see it and the library does not export the types (as in the library module), so I'm not able to import them:

```
import {type TypeName} from 'thisLibrary'; // results in "Module 'thisLibrary' has no exported member 'TypeName'".
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you're trying to use internal types/interfaces from some library that means something goes wrong: either you don't use it properly or the author(s) of the library made a mistake by not exporting some types. In the second case, it's better to create an issue in GutHub if this library is stored there.

Comment: The types do have "export" statement in the source file of the library and - as I wrote - compiler sees the definitions used in the imported function and provides tooltip for the types, so my understanding is that they did export them somehow? They just can't be imported with import statement like `import {TypeName } from 'thisLibrary'`. But I don't think they are meant to be `private`. But the compiler does not recognize the name when I write it in my own code to create a variable that I can pass to the imported function. So I guess I configured something incorrectly, the question is what?

Comment: It's hard to say if we don't have a link to this library and a real type of interface you're trying to import. Can you share this with us?

Comment: This is the library: https://javascript.rickandmortyapi.com/

Comment: And what type did you try to import?

Comment: I tried eg. "CharacterFilter".

Comment: Ok, did you try `import { CharacterFilter } from 'rickmortyapi/dist/interfaces'`. Did it work?

Comment: No, I didn't. I see that it does work - thank you! I could have tried some imports starting with 'node_modules', but I conclude this was too much. Please submit an answer if you would like it to get approved. Please use the 'thisLibrary' name in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to import directly from the file where the exported interface is located.

```
import { TypeName } from 'thisLibrary/dist/interfaces'
```

Answer (score 0):

[You said that the types are exported from the lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482114/how-to-import-types-from-a-third-party-library/70482394#comment124591334_70482114), so just import the type from the lib, like this:

```ts
import type {TypeName} from 'thisLibrary';
```

```ts
// or in TS version >=4.5
import {type TypeName} from 'thisLibrary';

let myVar: TypeName; // ok
```

[TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxgTzAUzgJTQQwMYwByEAJmgL5wBmUEIcA5FLgQwNxwD0ncz+MAAQCMAdgB0ABjEAmODngwAFhhigMEKnADuUYKoB2AcwCwAKDMAbNPH2k0ALiwsidtmbO2ycALyNlFiwh2Lh4IAGsPOx9qHAsAZzQObjhwyK9fAFd9MipgfTQSJNCI008MX30MgKKUsKA)

Comment: They are exported from the file they are defined in - yes. They are resolved for the purpose of imported function check - yes. But the import like you suggested ends with `Module 'thisLibrary' has no exported member 'TypeName'`

Comment: In that case, you have either not installed the package, or the package does not export the types correctly, and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482114/how-to-import-types-from-a-third-party-library#comment124591198_70482114) is correct: you should file an issue with the package repo.

Comment: In the meantime, you can just copy the type (and all of its dependent types) from the package into your module and use them directly as if you had authored them yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I definitely have installed package, as I'm succesfully importing actual function from it. I have copied the definitions temporarily, but thought I'm doing something wrong taht can be fixed.